# can't convert "[" with encoding "gb2312" to "utf-8" in ruby1.9.3

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

I'm learning ruby and try to get the filename from a ftp server. The string I got was encoded in ***gb2312(simplified Chinese)***, It's success in most cases with these codes:

```
str = str.force_encoding("gb2312")
str = str.encode("utf-8")
```

but it will make an error `"in encode': "\xFD" followed by "\x88" on GB2312 (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError)"` if the string contains the symbol `"["` or `"【"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby Encoding allows a lot of introspection. That way, you can find out pretty well, how to handle a given String:

```
"【".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
"【".valid_encoding?
=> true
"【".force_encoding("gb2312").valid_encoding?
=> false
```

That shows that this character is not with the given character-set! If you need to transform all those characters, you can use the `encode` method and provide defaults or replace undefined characters like so:

```
"【".encode("gb2312", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
=> "\x{A1BE}"
```

If you have a String that has mixed character Encodings, you are pretty screwed. There is no way to find out without a lot of guessing.